# keyup en google app script y suma de inputs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Tengo este calculador en google app script y necesito ayuda con algunos datos.
Abajo de todo en vez de sumar los valores, me pone los valores de los dos inputs que debieran sumarse, no sé que me falta o en que estoy fallando...
por otra parte, quiero ponerlo onchange o con keyup y no sé como pasar esa instrucción para que me funcione en la app.-

Si alguien lo puede mirar para corregir... Gracias

```js
function calcular(){
    var saldo = document.getElementById("saldo").value;
    var quita = document.getElementById("quita").value;
    var negociado =  document.getElementById("negociado").value;
    var honorarios = document.getElementById("honos").value;
    var cuotas = document.getElementById("cuotas").value;
    var honostot = document.getElementById("honostotal").value;
    var cuotpur = document.getElementById("cuotapura").value;
    var cuothon = document.getElementById("cuotahonos").value;
    var final =(saldo * quita) / 100;
        var descuento = saldo - final;
    document.getElementById("negociado").value = descuento;
    var hono = (negociado * honorarios) / 100;
    document.getElementById("honostotal").value = hono;
     var cuota1 = negociado / cuotas;
    document.getElementById("cuotapura").value = cuota1;
   var cuota2 = honostot / cuotas;
    document.getElementById("cuotahonos").value = cuota2;
        var totales = negociado + honostot;
    document.getElementById("totalconhonos").value = totales;
        var cuotatot = cuotpur + cuothon;
    document.getElementById("cuotatotal").value = cuotatot;
};
```

Comment: El valor de los inputs los coje como string, deberás pasarlos a enteros con `parseInt()`

Comment: ya resolví el tema de on keyup con addEventListener ,  pero sigo sin hacer que se sumen y no me doy cuenta el error

Comment: Ya te dije lo que debes hacer, eso te sale por que estas concatenando en vez de sumar

Comment: Si, estaba poniendo parseInt() mal ... ya lo tengo resuelto.. Gracias!

Comment: @GEV Te sugiero que publiques la solución como respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calcular(){
    var saldo = document.getElementById("saldo").value;
    var quita = document.getElementById("quita").value;
    var negociado =  document.getElementById("negociado").value;
    var honorarios = document.getElementById("honos").value;
    var cuotas = document.getElementById("cuotas").value;
    var honostot = document.getElementById("honostotal").value;
    var cpura = document.getElementById("cuotapura").value;
    var chonos = document.getElementById("cuotahonos").value;
    
    var final =(saldo * quita) / 100;
    
    var descuento = saldo - final;
    document.getElementById("negociado").value = descuento;

    var hono = (negociado * honorarios) / 100;
    document.getElementById("honostotal").value = hono;
        
    var cuota1 = parseInt(negociado) / cuotas;
    document.getElementById("cuotapura").value = cuota1;
    
    var cuota2 = parseInt(honostot) / cuotas;
    document.getElementById("cuotahonos").value = cuota2;
    
    var totales = parseInt(negociado) + parseInt(honostot);
    document.getElementById("totalconhonos").value = totales;
    
    var ctotal = parseInt(totales) / cuotas;
    document.getElementById("cuotatotal").value = ctotal;

};
```

resuelto